# How can we plot solid of revolution in Mathcad Prime?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, mathcad

I finded the answer for the exercise but I don't know how plot a 3D for the volume of answer.
[Click for image exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsCpL.png)